# ¿Cómo iniciar la ventana raíz como cuadro de diálogo o solo con el botón cerrar en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

En el caso de Tkinter he intentado de varias maneras iniciar la ventana raíz o clase principal sin los componentes básicos del marco de la ventana como *max/mín*, básicamente mi propósito antes que todo es volver la ventana raíz como cuadro de diálogo, es decir no mostrar ni en el marco de la ventana, ni en el menu contextual del sistema de la ventana los botones max/mín. Antes que responda, no asimile o marque como duplicado de otras preguntas ya que mi propósito es retirar estos componentes del marco de la ventana y **NO** como otras preguntas deshabilitar solo el botón de maximizar.

Con previa investigación me doy cuenta que *Tkinter* no administra las ventanas, algo que es lógico ya que su interprete es el lenguaje Tcl, por lo cual es imposible buscar una manera retirar estos botones del marco. La única manera en la cual *Tkinter* retira estos componentes es cuando la ventana es hija o `Toplevel()` de la raíz y por medio de `transient()` se eliminan los botones *max/mín*, por lo cual es la dependencia de la raíz y la raíz no puede ser `transient()` ya que el valor que retornaría es nulo y obviamente no es lógico.

Básicamente no es tanto código ya que es la definición de la raíz, la cual es `root` como identificador y clase principal:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Ejemplo ventana')
root.resizable(0,0)
```

**Nota:** De se cuenta que `resizable()` retorna el
parámetro de ventana mediante un valor booleano el cual si está en cero o False va a deshabitar el botón de maximizar, por lo cual si en casos hipotéticos
quiero deshabilitar el botón minimizar no funcionará.

**Usar otros atributos de ventana:**
Usar atributos de ventana en el caso de Tkinter puede llegar a ser funcional en varias ocasiones, aunque usar el método `('-toolwindow', True)` y otros métodos posibles para cambiar la apariencia del marco de la ventana no resultará útil para mi pregunta, básicamente el método más cercano el cual es `toolwindow` vuelve la ventana sin ningún botón *max/mín* aunque solo es para ventanas rápidas o de uso rápido como accesos a funciones o herramientas. Agradecería la respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso de Tkinter es totalmente cierto, ud no puede modificar ningún parámetro de la ventana en general ya que Tkinter depende de el administrador de ventanas *(X11)*, por lo cual la mayoría de los protocolos y estilos los maneja este administrador de ventanas, aunque si es posible modificar aplicando estilos globales externos los cuales los maneja la API de Windows *(win32)*. Tkinter en otras palabras en gran parte tiene el acceso más que todo al área cliente de la ventana o en otras palabras todos lo componentes gráficos y controles, mientras el área no cliente es el marco de la ventana, la barra de título, la barra de menús, el menú de la ventana, los botones de minimizar y maximizar, el borde de tamaño y las barras de desplazamiento se denominan colectivamente el área no cliente de la ventana.

El sistema gestiona la mayoría de los aspectos del área no cliente; la aplicación gestiona la apariencia y el comportamiento de su área de cliente, el cual es administrado en este caso por Tkinter como intérprete.

### Usando estilos de ventana con `ctypes` (`windll`):

> Tenga en cuenta que requiere la librería `ctypes` para cambiar el estilo
> de la ventana.

Este método es más complejo ya que ud debe definir cada estilo que ud va a usar, como la librería `ctypes` se comunica con objetos `windll` y `oledll` de Windows para cargar bibliotecas de vínculos dinámicos. En este caso ud se está comunicando con *user32.dll* el cual es un archivo dll para cargar funciones Windows API *(win32)*.

Cada estilo de la ventana está  integrado dentro del encabezado `winuser.h` el cual es un archivo en interfaces de programación *win32* C/C++ que tiene funciones y parámetros para las ventanas.

Este es el código:

```
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ctypes
import ctypes.wintypes
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

# Parámetros de la ventana (deshabilitar botones de la barra de la ventana) Win32 (Windows API)

GWL_STYLE = -16   #Llamada de SetWindowLongA función (winuser.h), GWL_STYLE
#-16 agrega un estilo nuevo.
WS_CHILD = 0x40000000
WS_SYSMENU = 0x00080000
WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000
WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000
WS_GROUP = 0x00020000
WS_MAXIMIZEBOX = 0x00010000
WS_BORDER = 0x00800000
WS_OVERLAPPED = 0x00000000
WS_DLGFRAME = 0x00400000
WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000
WS_TILED = 0x00000000

WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x00000001
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080
WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE = 0x00000100

SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020
SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010
SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002
SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001

GCL_STYLE = -26
CS_NOCLOSE = 0x0200


GetWindowLong = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW # Llamar user32.dll, derivada de la función GetWindowLongW(). 
#Más info consulte documentación
GetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
GetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT)

SetWindowLong = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW # No modificar esto
SetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
SetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT, wintypes.ULONG)

SetWindowPos = windll.user32.SetWindowPos

#====================================================
SetClassLong = windll.user32.SetClassLongW # Llamar user32.dll, derivada de la función SetClassLongW(). 
SetClassLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
SetClassLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT, wintypes.ULONG)

GetClassLong = windll.user32.GetClassLongW 
GetClassLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
GetClassLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT)

#====================================================

root = tk.Tk() # Ventana inicial de clase
root.geometry('396x439') # Tamaño de ventana  
root.geometry('+330+62') # Asignar una posición predeterminada
root.maxsize(396, 439)
root.minsize(396, 439)
root.resizable(0,0) # Se debe dejar como ventana no maximizable.
root.title('Ventana como cuadro de diálogo')

DialogButtonStyle = ttk.Style() 
DialogButtonStyle.configure('E.TButton', font =('Microsoft Sans Serif', 8))

def RetonarHwnd(): # Obtener id ventana como hwnd.
    w_id = root.winfo_id() # Obtener identificador de ventana
    style = GetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE) 
    newstyle = style & ~WS_CHILD
    res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, newstyle) 
    res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
    hwnd = int(root.wm_frame(), 16) 
    res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, style) 
    res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
    return hwnd   

def DialogoSinBotonesMaxMin():
    hwnd = RetonarHwnd()
    style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) 
    style = style & ~WS_GROUP
    res = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, style)
    res = SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)


LabelSettingInfo = tk.Label(root, text="Ventana en Tkinter sin botones\nmax/mín usando ctypes.", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9), justify='left')
LabelSettingInfo.place(x=55, y=120)


def closeProtocolModal():
    root.destroy()

btnOk = ttk.Button(root, text='Aceptar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=lambda:[closeProtocolModal()])
btnOk.place(x=224,y=406)


btnCancel = ttk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=closeProtocolModal)
btnCancel.place(x=308,y=406)

root.after(1, DialogoSinBotonesMaxMin) # Iniciar función para cambiar el estilo existente.
root.mainloop()
```

> Nota: Tenga en cuenta que esta es la definición global de cada estilo, nótese que cada estilo tiene un identificador hexadecimal por
> lo cual he definido los más usados. Usted puede borrarlos si no va a
> utilizar algunos de estos, aunque es recomendable para usar múltiples
> estilos. Para más información sobre los estilos y estilos extendidos [consulte la documentación oficial.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles)
>
> La función debe ejecutarse desde que se inicia la ventana ya que Tkinter de manera predeterminada carga la ventana, más no el estilo ya que los estilos solo se aplican una vez iniciada la ventana, por ello `DialogoSinBotonesMaxMin()` se debe iniciar para reemplazar el estilo predeterminado de Tkinter.

La función `DialogoSinBotonesMaxMin()` en este caso se encarga de alguna forma de sobrescribir el estilo predeterminado de Tkinter por uno totalmente distinto, retornando la ventana como un *HWND* o un identificador que usan las interfaces de programación *win32*. Fíjese que el estilo `WS_GROUP` convierte la ventana con los controles del área no cliente a los controles básicos primarios mostrando solo el botón de cierre y deshabilitando del menú contextual de la ventana las opciones de *max/mín* y Tamaño.

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Usando la librería Win32 (`pywin32`):

> Tenga en cuenta que requiere la librería `pywin32` para cambiar el estilo
> de la ventana.

Este método es más fácil ya que con sólo 2 líneas de código puede importar el estilo y aplicarlo en la ventana ya que al usar el módulo `win32ui` importa varios componentes de los estilos del área no cliente de la ventana a el estilo predeterminado que usa Tkinter a comparación de `ctypes`.

Este es el código:

```
import tkinter 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import win32ui
import win32con

root = tk.Tk() # Ventana inicial de clase
root.geometry('396x439') # Tamaño de ventana (la ventana no es maximizable) 
root.geometry('+330+62') # Asignar una posición predeterminada
root.maxsize(396, 439)
root.minsize(396, 439)
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title('Ventana como cuadro de diálogo usando Win32')

DialogButtonStyle = ttk.Style() 
DialogButtonStyle.configure('E.TButton', font =('Microsoft Sans Serif', 8))

LabelSettingInfo = tk.Label(root, text="Ventana en Tkinter sin botones\nmax/mín usando pywin32.", font=("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9), justify='left')
LabelSettingInfo.place(x=55, y=120)


def closeProtocolModal():
    root.destroy()

btnOk = ttk.Button(root, text='Aceptar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=lambda:[closeProtocolModal()])
btnOk.place(x=224,y=406)


btnCancel = ttk.Button(root, text='Cancelar', style= 'E.TButton', takefocus=False, command=closeProtocolModal)
btnCancel.place(x=308,y=406)

def DialogoSinBotonesMaxMinWin32(): # Sobrescribe el estilo existente
    Win32LoadStyleInTkClass = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(int(root.wm_frame(), 0))
    Win32LoadStyleInTkClass.ModifyStyle(win32con.WS_GROUP, 0, win32con.SWP_FRAMECHANGED)

root.after(1, DialogoSinBotonesMaxMinWin32) # Iniciar función para cambiar el estilo existente.
root.mainloop()
```

Este es el resultado como imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Nota: La mayoría de la documentación de estas librerías y módulos está en Inglés.
> Esta vez puse una imagen para que ud lo intente por sí mismo.

**Observaciones generales:**

- Ambos métodos son totalmente funcionales y se comportan igual.
- Ambos métodos yo los utilizo y son ideales para cualquier programa que ud esté desarrollando.
- Ambos métodos funcionan con los estilos que usa `winuser.h`, por lo cual usted debe saber los estilos que maneja la API de Windows (win32) para cambiar estilos de ventana.
- El primer método es más complejo ya que ud debe definir y comunicarse con *user32.dll*, mientras el segundo incluye de manera directa los estilos por medio de `win32ui` y `win32con`.
- Ambos métodos son trucos ya que Tkinter no puede aplicar estos estilos a sus ventanas, estos métodos en general previamente son difíciles de adaptar en Tkinter ya que Tkinter no funciona bien con la API de Windows.
- Si usted no aplica bien los estilos, puede colapsar su ventana o quedar inactiva o congelada. Para más info consulte los [estilos que maneja](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) `winuser.h`.
- Ambos métodos también sirven para aplicar otros estilos como deshabilitar el botón de **minimizar** del área no cliente, algo que no es posible en Tkinter. Debe quitar `root.resizable()` ya que Tkinter está aplicando ya un estilo y no se pueden aplicar múltiples estilos para el área no cliente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]